# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: android

```
[2011-04-11 13:27:36 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:573)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:349)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:419)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:840)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:808)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:767)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:635)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:563)
```

Comment: The same thing happened to me, it was because I connected my phone via Wi-Fi to the computer (I was passing internet from the computer to the phone)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This problem can be simply solved by closing Eclipse and restarting it. Eclipse sometimes fails to establish a connection with the Emulator, so this can happen in some cases.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I have to perform a full restart of my computer when this happens (which is frequently!)

Comment: @Nate if you restart adb as well (adb kill-server/adb start-server), does that save you from restarting the computer?

Comment: Many thanks, Bjorn.  I had indeed found another link, and on its advice, wrote myself a .bat script that does "adb disconnect" and then "adb kill-server".  That fixes the problem without a restart.  Thanks again for following up!

Comment: Same problem. I had JetBrains IDEA running. Closing IDEA helped.

Comment: Eclipse kepler can not connect to the DB in my case. I changed it to helios and it works fine.

Comment: Not only eclipse.Android studio also seems to be like that

Answer (score 69):

Checkout there might be two instances of Eclipse are pointing to same Android SDK...just keep one instance of Eclipse and try again...that's why you are getting Exception as "established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"...go in details of android adb(Android Debug Bridge) you will get it...

Comment: My problem was 2 eclipse instances running!

Comment: Or alternatively, Android Studio and Eclipse. :)

Answer (score 19):

I was getting these errors too and was stumped.
After reading and trying the two answers above, I was still getting the error.

However,I checked the processes tab of Task Manager to find a rogue copy of 'eclipse.exe *32' that the UI didn' t show as running. I guess this should have been obvious as the error does suggest that the reason the emulator/phone cannot connect is because it's already established a connection with the second copy.

Long story short, make sure via Task Manager that no other Eclipse instances are running before resorting to a PC restart!

Comment: Also check that there aren't any emulator process leftovers

Answer (score 10):

If you develop in multiple IDE's or other programs that connect to AVD you should try closing them too.

Netbeans also can cause conflicts with eclipse if you set it up for NBAndroid.

Answer (score 6):

I had the problem with multiple IDE. Closing Eclipse, killing from task manager or restarting didnt help. Just deleted the AVD and created it again.

Answer (score 6):

SOLUTION :-

1. I was getting the same error as I was opening two eclipse window, so I close one eclipse window and run the app again. You will not get the error.
2. restart(close and start) the eclipse again if you have open only one eclipse window.

Answer (score 3):

This problem may occur if you have two devices connected to the computer at the same time. Adb does not support reaching both devices via command/console. So, if you debug your app after connecting and disconnecting the second device you will most probably have this problem. One solution might be restarting adb and/or eclipse if necessary. It can be quite annoying sometimes and I am afraid there is no other solution to that.

Answer (score 3):

This problem may also occur when you are opening Android Studio and Eclipse at once. Try to close one of them and it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

In My Case, I was running **Android Studio** and **Eclipse** at a time. AS and Eclipse were trying to communicate a device/emulator through **adb**.

Solution:
I closed Android Studio. Then I restarted Eclipse.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Close the emulator if already opened.
Right click on your project ->Run as -> run configurations -> Run.
After the emulator launched:  Right click on your project ->Run as ->android project.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue on my Windows 7 64-bit development machine when running Android Studio 2.1.x and Android Studio 2.2.x side-by-side.

I had deployed an application via the 2.2.x instance the previous day and had left that IDE running. The next day I deployed a different application from the 2.1.x IDE and this is when I encountered the issue.

Shutting down both IDEs and then restarting the 2.1.x IDE resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the eclipse will solve the problem and kill the "adb disconnect" and then "adb kill-server"

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows box, I wanted to avoid reboot and these did not work:
* /android/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
* /android/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server

So what did work to get adb running again without this error was

1. wait for the TIME WAIT to complete, which took multiple minutes.  You can view the state of the ports and watch when to restart the debugger with this command: "PortQryV2/PortQry.exe -local" This tools is downloaded here: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=832919
2. force closing ports with "netsh int tcp reset"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me (under windows) was to reopen the IDE as administrator.  All worked smoothly after that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by closing Eclipse and restarting it again. Eclipse sometimes fails to establish a connection with the Emulator/device, so this can happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Running Eclipse Luna and using WifiADB app on my phone I started getting this error when Running my app from Eclipse. Oddly, in Indigo (I installed Luna last night) it was working fine.

The problem for me was I had the phone connected to the PC to charge it, and even when running a .bat script to kill ADB it appeared that a second instance was started when Run. Plugging the phone into the monitor to charge when debugging over wifi solved it. I need to debug on wifi sometimes to test my app stopping/starting on power state change.

Of course it reasonable to assume (highly likely) I've just not set Luna up the same.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appear if two software use same port
generally Android studio use the port 5037
try to close the port by cmd according to your operating system
then reboot your Android studio or your Eclipse

Answer (score -2):

I was having this problem. 
Things I tried:

1. Restart Eclipse
2. Restart Eclipse & Kill adb as mentioned here.
3. Restart Machine & Open Eclipse

This is what worked for me

1. Powered off (pulled plug) my android device, Restart Machine, Power
   on android device.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -2):

1. Close Eclipse
2. Open Task Manager and kill adb.exe
3. Start Eclipse
   It should work.