# Android Emulator error -ddmlib error

Tags: android, ioexception, device-manager

When test my codes by elumator  ,Eclipse console  show this error(but application Debug is OK):

```
[2011-12-28 13:30:26 - ddmlib]Your host of software to suspend a already established connection。
java.io.IOException: Your host of software to suspend a already established connection
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)
```

give me some tips.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine

Answer (score 0):

Create bridge with Force new Bridge = false

This will not create new Bridge and use the existing one I guess!

```
AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge("PATH/TO/ADB/adb",false);
```

Let us know if this worked!