# android app doesn't show on the emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I made an android application using eclipse and it is working fine when I started developing my app. But then as I continue to develop the app the emulator seems to be not updating the application prior to the changes I have made on the code. So I tried deleting my avd and create a new one every time I run my app, and that seems to have worked.

**Now my problem is that my emulator doesn't show my app. It says "Failed to install *.apk on device 'emulator-5554': An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine".**

I searched for ways to solved it but none of it seems to have worked. I tried killing the adb process (as most my searches would say) on the task manager but still my app doesn't show on the emulator. The emulator is running and all but my icon is nowhere to be found. Am I misssing out something? Is the problem connected to the first problem i had before?

As I said, I started developing android app recently, so please bear with me. :) I appreciate all your help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question but not exactly the same. May have some solutions for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252416/adb-install-uploading-of-apk-taking-ages

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine

Question is same like above links

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine

Question is same like this and also solution is there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating/using different emulator?
That usually solves all puzzles I am having!

Comment: I tried to remember what I did before this problem happened, and so I remembered that I did add a music background which is 50+ MB in size. So I removed that and the app showed on the emulator. Now my problem is that I don't how to incorporate big file sizes (for videos or music) in it without crashing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: For me the big file sizes isn't problem if I am patient, it takes ages to load big files but will actually do it. Is it possible that you could use phone to develop as its a lot faster than emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just restart eclipse and adb server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

They will reconnected.