# adb install over usb not working

Tags: android, bash, apk, adb

I have a bash script running in work which automates the install of various APK samples (some malicious, some not - for testing purposes) to a HTC Desire Z handset running Sophos AV.

Runs well but every now and then an APK will try to install and the shell prompt will just hang at install. At the same time Sophos detects it as malicious but instead of displaying a box offering to uninstall it, it displays a box to delete it instead. Whether this is connected to the adb install issue I'm not sure but it's happened everytime.

It appears to install ok (2539 KB/s (634874 bytes in 0.244s)) .Package size is 640k.

I am running the command adb install -s /location/of/sample.apk

Any ideas?

Sorry for the lengthy post

Thanks

Comment: Similar questions with more potential solutions to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296305  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252416

Answer (score 7):

In case this helps others I had a different problem with similar symptoms. ADB install -r "apk path" would hang indefinitely.

**I troubleshooted a myriad of things and identified that it was my USB cable length.**

I have an USB extender cable as that I plug my devices into. The combined length of my device's cable and the USB extender cable caused this issue. Removing the extension cable fix the issue and eventually I replaced my USB extender cable with a shorter extension cable for the final solution.

Comment: Plugging the same USB cable into a different port did it for me.

Comment: A poor or broken short cable can do this as well.  Replacing with a good cable nipped the marginal behavior in the bud.

Answer (score 5):

try restarting adb server:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: tried this. I restart the script after every sample is tested. I have also run the sample problem sample manually out of the script and it still hangs

Comment: Also try restarting the phone.

Comment: thanks, I tried the phone as well, but no difference. Apologies I have added a lot more to the initaly question.. might help diagnose

Comment: this helped me with adb install hanging at install to emulator

Answer (score 0):

Have you added udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for type of device you want to use.Incase you havn't that may be a reason for this issue. Execute 'lsusb -v' in Terminal. This will give information regarding Unique Vendor id of each connected device in a list.Find the Vendor id of your device.Once you identify the vendor id follow the instructions given in the link for Ubuntu environment. link:http://zoumpis.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/using-hardware-devices-while-developing-and-android-application/

Comment: appreciate all the advice but this problem definitely seems to be connected with the malicious sample I am attempting to install. I have since tried installing (via the same command) and all samples install correctly before going through the detection phase of my bash script.