# ADB commandline Hanging during install (PhoneGap)

Tags: android, cordova, adb

My Phonegap app refuses to load onto my Android device (even the HellowWorld default app is refusing to load)

Everything was running just great until today.
Here's my console log:

```
***\>adb devices
List of devices attached
4c05609b        device

***\>phonegap run --device -V android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
[phonegap] Compiling app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c ***\platforms\android\cordova\build
[phonegap] Platform "android" compiled successfully.
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] installing app onto device
[phonegap] Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
[phonegap] Running app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c ***\platforms\android\cordova\run --device
```

It just sits there saying running... forever.

I have another terminal window open with `adb logcat` running and at some point (maybe 10-15 seconds into that last line getting printed) it stops logging. Termination of the process and subsequent calls to `adb logcat` result in more hanging (no logging at all)

So then I have to do a kill-server, start-server to break out of this endless hanging at which point the phonegap process terminates with:

```
       [error] An error occurred while running the android project.
***\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to d
evice: Error executing "adb -s 4c05609b install -r "***\platforms\android\bin\Po
ached-debug-unaligned.apk"": protocol failure
```

**I have tried::**

- deleting my .cordova folder in C:\Users\Name
- running the adb install directly (without phonegap)
- deploying to an emulator (same problem)
- unplugging / replugging the device
- rebooting all devices
- toggling "developer mode" on the device and revoking USB debugging privileges

I am all out of ideas!

Would greatly appreciate any tips or leads.

*ADB version 1.0.31*

*Galaxy S3 running Android v4.3*

---

**EDIT:**

Deploying to an emulator claims to complete successfully, but the app never opens and does not appear in the app list inside the emulator. So I have no way of actually testing it on the emulator either.

Would really appreciate some assistance.

---

**EDIT 2:**

After some further tinkering I've discovered my issue can be more specifically described as *ADB hangs (freezes) when I attempt to talk to my device.* I've determined this because *adb shell*, *adb install*, and *adb push* all fail the same way as described above. No error, just finite waiting.

*adb logcat*, *adb devices*, and other read functions work perfectly fine until one of the aforementioned write functions hangs in which case I need to do a *adb kill-server* or *TASKKILL* to get *adb logcat* working again.

Not sure if this added information helps, but there you go. The last thing I haven't yet tried is to do a factory reset on my phone as suggested by [this fellow](http://androidforums.com/epic-4g-all-things-root/197424-cant-get-adb-shell-command.html). If I can't find a solution soon I will back up my data as best I can and attempt this...

Please save me before this becomes my last option!

Comment: Couple questions: What device are you using? What version of android is it running? Have you updated the OS recently, or have your USB debugging setting changed?

Comment: I'll include as an edit but it's an S3 running Android 4.3. I haven't made any changes. It was working great for a couple weeks then suddenly (mid day) it started hanging. I have since randomly gotten the HelloWorld app to install, but it's about once ever 30 tries and it's totally unreliable.

Comment: have you tried restarting the device? I got the same situation in my galaxy Grand. I have restared my device and there wasn't any issue after that

Comment: Yes I restarted the device. I also started using a second device (Nexus S running 4.2) which has the same problems. The issue seems to be more sporadic now. It fails in the manner described above, but after a few (nonconstant and seemingly arbitrary number) calls to adb kill-server I can get a build to my phone. Still wondering what the root cause is...

Comment: I have this issue as well when working inside of a VM. Funny thing is I have another VM (very similar) for a different project and it doesn't suffer from the same behaviour when using the same device.

Answer (score 16):

In case this helps others I had a problem with similar symptoms. ADB install -r "apk path" would hang indefinitely.

**I troubleshooted a myriad of things and identified that it was my USB cable length.**

I have an USB extender cable as that I plug my devices into. The combined length of my device's cable and the USB extender cable caused this issue. Removing the extension cable fix the issue and eventually I replaced my USB extender cable with a shorter extension cable for the final solution.

Comment: I was almost crying here trying to fix my stuff, then I read your commend and tested with other cable... worked. I will surely buy you a beer for that.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava if this answer helped, vote on it! :)

Comment: Plugging the same USB cable into a different port did it for me.

Comment: Changing cables did it for me, but I found the new cable required that I hold it in a certain position in order for the device to register that it was plugged in at all. This probably came down to the cable or port being a little dodgy, so I set things up to install over WIFI instead (see https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root) and now there is no cable to cause problems! Soo much better so far.

Answer (score 9):

The issues seems to resolve itself randomly. As others suggested, an arbitrary combination of ADB kill-server, restarting the device, and re-installing SDKs seems to alleviate the problem (even if only for a couple pushes).

I still have no idea what causes this hanging and, though superstitiously believe the arbitrary combination described above *fixes* it, am unsure how to permanently resolve it.

**To future people reading this**, until a solid explanation is given my only advice is to square away an hour or so to restart / rebuild your dev environment... and make sure you buy a durable stress ball.

Comment: I have had a similar problem of which when searching for it, I left the console alone in the hung state.  When I returned after researching this it started to install after around 2 min. of waiting.

Comment: After I have waited some minutes I pressed Ctrl+C. The adb terminal showed success and was available again.

Answer (score 3):

Shot in the dark here, but some more things to try:

1. Are you on a work PC or something? Make sure you have USB write permissions. Also, try different USB ports and cables. You have the latest USB driver for your devices right?
2. Try updating the SDK tools. Or maybe something got corrupted and a re-install might do the trick.
3. You have free space on your devices right?
4. Unknown sources is checked on both devices?
5. What version of Android are you targeting?

Answer (score 2):

Do try restart the device like other suggested. From my experience, kill the adb process, then run the cordova run command helps magically sometimes.

Comment: Killing the `adb` process in task manager (windows), then `adb kill-server`, then `adb start-server` then unplugin/replugin the device do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adb seemed to hang, but in fact the data transfer from Mac to emulator was really slow:

```
$ adb push platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/
150 KB/s (15587200 bytes in 101.223s)
```

It's a lot faster on USB connected real device. Don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same (original) issue (with cordova / testing on an old device) ie. hang during install.

Tried running adb install directly from cmd line ...

```
adb [-s <deviceID>] install <apk>
```

...and same issue so not cordova specific....

Opened android device monitor (ADM) ...

..sdk\tools>monitor

..and ran install from cmd line again and saw logcat message saying package was sdk 16 / device was 15...doh!

So went back to AndroidManifest.xml and changed android:minSdkVersion to 15 and all back to normal again - install worked fine.

( Issue arose because I had installed something else which had changed the minSdkVersion and then removed the something else and never reset the minSdkVersion )

So, possibly device sdk / android version is too low for your build. If not, a look at the ADM logcat output as you initiate the install from the command line might indicate what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

Unplugging and plugging device again usually helps.