# Why doesn't running the app on the emulator show the app on the emulator browse screen after installation?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-studio

My app runs and installed fine on my GenyMotion emulator device. However after I launch the app on the emulator and press the back button, I don't see the app on the Android app browse screen. Here is what I see in the app browse screen.
[image]

And I know this app is installed because when I go to settings -> Apps, here is what I see(Demo-App-)
[image]

Is there a reason why the app won't show up on the app browse screen? I didn't have this issue when I used eclipse(with android plugin). Is the issue with some setting in Android Studio 1.0? I like a quick way of starting the app and testing it without having to run it from Android Studio each time.

I tried looking on other threads but couldn't find the issue
The issue can't be [android app doesn't show on the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180815/android-app-doesnt-show-on-the-emulator) because my app installed fine.

Comment: Does your app have an Activity with LAUNCHER category?

Comment: ohh thank you, that was the issue. So the Android OS uses that category?

Comment: This category is used to specify an Activity as the main entry point to your application. The system will add an icon to the Launcher and will open the Activity once the user selects the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Egor's comment, When I looked closely at my Android Manifest, here's what I saw

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:category="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                />
       </intent-filter>
```

category should be its own tag, that is

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```