# error using deployment on my phone

Tags: android, spring, rest, jboss6.x

Hi i am using spring for android with an app server jboss6 , in the emulator all works corectly but when i deployed my app on my phone i have this error 
my app is 2.3.3 and my phone is android 4

```
[2012-04-18 15:20:30 - ddmlib] Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
java.io.IOException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:33)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:72)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:43)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
 at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:854)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:822)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:781)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:649)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identical question was answered here: [An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine)

In short: close eclipse -> kill adb -> start eclipse

Comment: it's ok   now but i have this new error   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage.pfe/mypackage.pfe.ListCategorieActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @AhmedDrira "NetworkOnMainThreadException" goes away if you use an AsyncTask, Thread or something similar to do the network I/O on a background thread.