# App not uploading to Emulator

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine)

i am getting error message on console while trying to upload in emulator.

```
[2012-10-08 14:20:22 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

Comment: first try with restart your emulator..

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to restart eclipse. normally it is enough to restart the adb-server:

- open your shell / cmd window
- cd to your platform-tools directory
- type "adb kill-server"
- type "adb start-server"
- when the emulator is still running you should find it with "adb devices"
- then you should be able to install your app normally via eclipse

hope this helps