# Why can not I read bytes from the TcpClient in C#?

Tags: sockets, asp.net-core, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Why can not I read bytes from the TcpClient in C#?

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Here is how I start my TcpClient:

```
    public static async void Start()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 13000);
            server.Start();

            var client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            var stream = client.GetStream();
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("ABCD");
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(server != null)
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how I run a request to the TcpClient:

```
try {
    var response = (new HttpClient()).GetByteArrayAsync("http://localhost:13000").Result;
    return Convert.ToBase64String(response);
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw;
}
```

The `return Convert.ToBase64String(response);` line is never reached. While I see the quoted above error message inside the `Exception e` if I hit a breakpoint on the `throw` line.

Also, during debug the `Start()` method completes just fine. I.e. it starts, then wait for a request, gets a request, writes to the TclClient and at the end runs the `server.Stop();` command.

I am expecting my code to work, because I took it and modified from the official documentation over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netcore-3.1).

I tried to check out a few resources which would tackle my exception, but none of them did help.

E.g. I tried to use [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304658/c-sharp-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machi) question.

First answer tells nothing useful actually, but just plays around with words and at the end states that one can do nothing about the exception (please, correct me if I am missing a point in the answer).

And the second answer tells an impossible in my case problem. Because, I am sure there is nothing running on the 13000 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1), which sends an HTTP request and expects an HTTP response. But your server is not an HTTP server, it is just a plain TCP server, so the client is likely to fail and forcibly close the connection when it doesn't receive a properly formatted HTTP response.

The "official documentation" whose example you modified is not using `HttpClient` at all, it is using [`TcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

If you want to use `HttpClient` in your client, then you should use [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `TcpListener` in your server.