# Uploading zip file with .bundle using autodesk design automation sdk v3 return an error

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

What could be the cause of this, I can't upload the zip file which contains .bundle, I followed this sample code from https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation/blob/main/src/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation/Http/AppBundlesApi.gen.cs as well as from [https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-customproperty-revit](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-customproperty-revit/blob/691ae77e3cc5c86ab4b0d801eb28f4f821d04b21/webapp/Controllers/DesignAutomation4Revit.cs#L117) however, I couldn't make it work, it return error when calling the **ExecuteAsync** function.

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

The inner exception:

> Unable to read the data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

This is the part where the error occurred:

```
RestClient uploadClient = new RestClient(newAppVersion.UploadParameters.EndpointURL);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.Post);
request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> x in newAppVersion.UploadParameters.FormData) request.AddParameter(x.Key, x.Value);
request.AddFile("file", packageZipPath);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
var response = await uploadClient.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

Before it reaches to that part, I was able to get the token and able to create a nickname successfully.

Comment: This might not directly be related to design automation. It is more about usage of the code sample (which I am not as familiar with in this case). However it is likely that you have multiple processes claiming the same port. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63857129/11057988). Check your task manager.

Comment: Thank you @RahulBhobe, the code actually doesn't throw an error in that line **ExecuteAsync**, I just noticed when I debug it the response from ExecuteAsync contains StatusCode=0 and the ErrorException message. The code continues to run until the submission of the workitem where it stops and complain that the appBundles cannot be found.
 
I checked the [link](https://da-manager.autodesk.io/#) and I saw the appBundles I just created there. Does it mean I successfully created the appBundles? If yes, but how come the **CreateWorkItemAsync** function couldn't find it?

Comment: Could you update the description with the new error you mentioned? Without looking into it, the best I could guess is that the app bundle meta data is uploaded to design automation, but the actual bundle zip is not uploaded yet.

Comment: I was told to use this instead **await daClient.CreateAppBundleAsync(appBundleSpec, label, packageZipPath);** and it works, I haven't encountered the issue above.

Comment: So, is everything OK now for you?

Comment: Yes, all is working now. Thank you all for your help