# Error sending email from ASP.NET webforms C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am attempting to resolve an issue with sending emails from an ASP.NET webforms site. The email is sent to other addresses, but not the one I need it to go to. I am struggling to figure out what the issue is.

My code for sending the emails:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = txtName.Text;
    string EmailAddress = txtEmail.Text;
    string phone = "Number not supplied";

    if (txtPhone.Text != "")
    {
        phone = txtPhone.Text;
    }

    string SendAddress = @"emailsender@address.com";
    string Subject = "Message from Top Tree Fellas Website";
    string Message = Regex.Replace(txtMsg.Text, @"\r\n?|\n", "<br />");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAddress) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Message))
    {
        lblError.Text = "Please ensure all required fields are filled in.";
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();                                
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(@"email@address.co.uk"));
            msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(@"email@address2.com"));
            msg.Subject = Subject;
            msg.From = new MailAddress(SendAddress);

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            msg.Body = "<p><strong>Contact Name:</strong> " + Name + "<br />";
            msg.Body += "<strong>Email Address:</strong> " + EmailAddress + "<br />";
            msg.Body += "<strong>Phone:</strong> " + phone + "<br />";
            msg.Body += "<strong>Message:</strong><br />" + Message + "</p>";

            msg.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(EmailAddress));

            SmtpClient smtpClnt = new SmtpClient("smtp.ionos.co.uk");
            //smtpClnt.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClnt.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"emailsender@address.com", "password");
            smtpClnt.EnableSsl = true;

            smtpClnt.Send(msg);

            lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtMsg.Text = "";
            txtPhone.Text = "";

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Message sent');</script>");
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            string er1 = er.Message + "<br />" + er.InnerException;
            lblError.Text = er1;
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Something went wrong. Please try again later or call us on: 07719 306404');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I get:

> Failure sending mail.

The inner exception:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
> at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpPooledStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> at System.IO.Stream.Close()
> at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
> at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
> at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"Any pointers would be greatly appreciated."_ - May I ask what part of the exception message you're having trouble understanding?

Comment: Top be honest, all of it. I haven't worked on asp.net for several years so I am a little lost.

Comment: Your computer or the network your computer is a part of has a firewall which is configured to prevent outgoing smtp connections. Talk to your administrator to discuss further options

Comment: It works for other email addresses though?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304658/c-sharp-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machi - we can't really help you - you'll need to run Wireshark locally and see what's going on.

Comment: Try removing one of the To addresses (CC) and see if it does anything.