# Why am I getting these errors in DDMS when running android application?

Tags: android, console

So as the question says, I am getting these errors when running my android application. I switch the Console to Android, then when running the app it returns to DDMS and shows these :

```
[2013-02-21 22:12:53 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:575)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:421)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

what does it mean? The emulator itself does not also accept mouse inputs (or it seems to not be) as when I click the launcher icon nothing happens when the emulator loads. So I just wait for the android application's first activity to launch.

Comment: I think it needs a restart..(Or system reboot might be a better option)

Comment: Look here as this question was asked before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine   You may want to inspect your usb cable for damages (perhaps its going bad?)

Comment: I am actually not using a USB cable. I am using an emulator through Eclipse. Not an actual device. But a virtual device, specifically the 7" WSVGA default

Comment: Is your device/emulator is creating a new socket (for communication purpose)? I had similar problems today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Solution 
These problem can be simply solved by closing Eclipse and restarting it again. Eclipse sometimes fails to establish a connection with the Emulator, so this can happen in some cases.

Comment: restarted the laptop and it worked right back to normal. I would still like to know what causes this though

Comment: What about the people who use Android Studio?(Eclipse is not supported for Android development anymore).