# Cannot start AVD emulator in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've tried creating different emulators in Eclipse and each time I am getting this error. I don't have two instances of Eclipse running....

```
[2013-03-24 16:02:40 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:89)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:450)
        at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:605)
        at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:451)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:837)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:805)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:765)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

Things I've tried:

- [An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine?rq=)
- Restarting PC AND Eclipse

It used to work before I updated the ADT and SDK via Eclipse. I can connect to my device and run my app from there though...

Comment: Perhaps there's some sort of permissions problem? Have you ever been able to run an emulator? Have you tried running it directly from the command line (without Eclipse running)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconnect ADB.  This can be done from the 'Devices Perspective' menu (last button on teh right, the upside triangle has an option to 'Reset ADB').

You can also reset the ADB from the command line with the following commands:

```
abd kill-server
```

then

```
and start-server
```