# Trouble using jsoup with Android 4.2

Tags: android, jsoup

I have an android app that uses jsoup that runs fine on a motorola atrix phone running Android 2.3.6 and also works fine on a Samsung Galaxy Tab running 2.3.5.

However, I have tried to run it on my new phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 runnning Android 4.2.2. It can't run jsoup at all.

It chokes on this line of code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(SPOT_SERVER_BASE).get();
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem for Android 4.2? (Or 4.1 or 4.0?) Is there something I need to do differently to get it to work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the value of SPOT_SERVER_BASE and what exception it throws?

Comment: SPOT_SERVE_BASE is a string that is the url of the website I am pulling data from. I think its IOException something like "Bad filename or directory" but it makes no sense because it works in Android 2.3

Comment: I cannot help you a lot if I don't know the exact exception. You could add jsoup sources jar to the libsrc folder and trace the reason for exception.

Comment: Here's what it wrote to the console:  "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Comment: Did you try `Clean` before building?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out what causes the problem, but I have figured out how to fix it.

In the manifest, I deleted this line: 
    android:targetsdkversion="xx"

where "xx" is whatever version you are using for the target in your build.

The only place where I indicate the project build targtet is where you edit the project properties by right-clicking on the package name and selecting "properties".

Why does this work? I have no idea.