# How to launch several instances of eclipse (multiple workspaces) and have ADT plugin working?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I have a problem with `eclipse` and `ADT plugin` when I want to launch several instances of eclipse.

---

### What is working (only one instance of eclipse)

I launch a **workspace with my Android projects** where I can debug and everything's fine.

I switch to **another one with my Web projects** and it also works.

---

### What is not working (two instances of eclipse)

The problem is that when I launch these eclipse instance with another workspace, I've got the following problem :

```
[2013-07-15 11:12:50 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Here is the problem : [An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine)

I know how to restart eclipse and it solves my problem when it happens with one instance.
With two instances of eclipse, it doesn't solve the problem at all.

---

### What I want (one instance of eclipse with ADT working AND another one with my Web Projects)

I could have two eclipse installations and launch one with ADT plugin installed and launch the other one where I haven't installed ADT, but I would like to have only one installed eclipse...

### How to solve this problem ?

- workspace configuration ?
- eclipse configuration ?
- ADT configuration ?
- anything else ?

Comment: A shot in the dark: Have you tried multiple ADT installation? and point each Eclipse to a different one...?

Comment: I don't want multiple ADT. One is enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the ADT plugin within one workspace, and ensure ADT isn't installed in the other workspace, you can have to instances open.

Running two separate instances of Eclipse from different workspaces will work very poorly if both instances are trying to connect to the device through ADB, because:

1. The device state as reflected in the Devices list may be mismatched
2. The debugger may not attach to the correct instance of Eclipse, causing:

   - The app may remain displaying the dialog reading "waiting for debugger"
   - The debugger may detach while running

I've tried getting this set up as well, and I'm afraid there simply isn't a solution for this.

Comment: I'm running about 3 to 4 instances of Eclipse all with Android workspaces. It "works", however I get regular issues in the console (which popups) and a dialog popup at times complaining it couldn't connect. As for logcat I'm usually able to read it from any workspace, but I have to hide the console somewhere. Other than those annoying popups everything works ok.

Comment: @3c71 then how did you do it?