# java.io.IOException while copying assets to sdcard (with assethelper)

Tags: java, android, java-io, assets

I used the code provided in some other question that is supposed to be correct and I have no reason to doubt that it is, yet now when I launch the app all I get is this:

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:763)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

the method that is used for copying is launched from Main activity and is as follows:

```
private void copyAssets()
{
    //iegust failu sarakstu
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "didnt get", e);
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
          Log.d("tag","Success");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Didnt copy: " + filename, e);
        }       
    }
}
//kope failu
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: "no reason to doubt that it is" <- obviously you do, it's called an `Exception`

Comment: what I meant was written by a chimpanze who doesn't know what he is doing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine this link may help you

Comment: I have tried everything from the similar questions asked, closing, restarting etc hasn't helped yet :(

Comment: you used permission in manifest file?

Comment: Whenever you back reply me its working or not bcoz most of the times i also have small errors of these types.

Answer (score 1):

To write files in the sdcard you have to give the permission on the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: No, I had done it already, before I posted the question. Unfortunatelly, I haven't located the problem yet.

Comment: you checked link suggested by Gaurav Gupta?

Answer (score 0):

can you post your Manifest? you should add the below permissions to your MANIFEST

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```