# android An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, android

```
[2014-03-30 19:55:57 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:642)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:488)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:763)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

Hello, the problems occur after run the SQLite application (in Eclipse), I search a lot of similar questions, but none of the solution can solve my problem.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

The pictures of problem as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtMk3.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK8zO.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There might be a chance that two eclipse instance are running on your machine. Try restarting eclipse and/or restart adb. Check below link for the similar issue.

[An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine)

Comment: So you can only have one eclipse process up at a time?

Comment: No not like that. You can have multiple eclipse running at same time but with different workspaces. But you can have only one DDMS instance running. As soon as you try to launch an eclipse with ADT plugin, it automatically launches an instance of DDMS as well.

Comment: @committedandroider no two instance (Eclipse or Studio) should be running simultaneously and pointing to same android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure you just have one instance of Eclipse running (No other instance of Eclipse or Studio running that is pointing to your same android SDK).
2. If above setup is correct try killing and restarting adb server by `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`
3. If even this does not work consider restarting your Eclipse or your machine.