# After deploying in tomcat , getting exception : established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

[I found the same question here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618664/an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine)
The solution discussed there was just to restart the eclipse/android studio, its fine in development machine. But in the production, the application is deployed in tomcat server 8 and getting the same issue after several request and response.
is something related database pooling or am I missing any configuration for database connection in spring boot?

Application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/testapi
server.port = 8070

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.2.25:1521/orcl
spring.session.store-type=none
spring.datasource.username=testapi
spring.datasource.password=testapi
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```

Exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:124) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:121) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:491) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]



    org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:396) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:421) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:409) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2085) ~[jackson-core-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:457) ~[jackson-core-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.SqlDateSerializer.serialize(SqlDateSerializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.SqlDateSerializer.serialize(SqlDateSerializer.java:16) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1392) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:271) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.37]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.37]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: The information is not sufficient to answer but how a request is made to your server? Is it an API call or a Servlet printing HTML?

Comment: please remove // from spring.datasource.url like "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.25:1521/orcl"

Comment: @CuriousMind  its an API call

Comment: @sreeroop this need not be a server side issue. Looking at the stack trace, it may happen that the client invoking the API might have disconnected the connection  before server could flush complete response. Causes could be response timeout, network failure at client end etc.